# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a problem where my url is seen as an invalid url. None of my URLS are working for my Django Application. I have made the mistake of using the same secret key that I used for another application. Here is a picture of my error message, url page, and my views.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Av23.jpg)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBpbB.jpg)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pugVz.jpg)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import Products

#This is the store view
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

#This is the About Us page view
def AboutUs(request):
    return render(request,'AboutUs.html')

#This is the Long Arm Services View
def LongArmServices(request):
    return render(request,'LongArmServices.html')

#This is the product View
def product(request):
    return render(request,'product.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.http import HttpResponse


app_name='home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('about_us/',views.AboutUs,name='AboutUs'),        path('long_arm_services/',views.LongArmServices,name='LongArmServices'),
    path('product/',views.product,name='product'),
]
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images* of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: views.py: from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import Products

#This is the store view
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

#This is the About Us page view
def AboutUs(request):
    return render(request,'AboutUs.html')

#This is the Long Arm Services View
def LongArmServices(request):
    return render(request,'LongArmServices.html')

#This is the product View
def product(request):
    return render(request,'product.html')

Comment: please [edit] the question. The problem is a combination of the template and the `urls.py`. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `urls.py` specify an `app_name = 'home'`, so that means you need to prefix the name of the view with the `app_name` and a colon (`:`). So you should rewrite the marked part in the template to:

```
href="{% url 'home:home' %}"
```